# How can I pass multiple options to getattr as a single variable?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def myfunction(con, command, options=None):
    if options != None:
        return getattr(con, command)(options)

returnvalue = myfunction(fromcon, 'search', (None, 'all'))
```

I need to change it so that it does the same thing as:

```
returnvalue = getattr(fromcon, 'search')(None, 'all')
```

Help.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `*args` syntax:

```
def myfunction(con,command,options=None):
    if options is not None:
        return getattr(con,command)(*options)

returnvalue = myfunction(fromcon,'search',(None,'all'))
```

You can read more about how this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Comment: Hah, that seems to have done it. Just have to change all my other options to (mystring,) and it doesn't divide them into letters. Thanks.